# changes to web.config or app_code folder doesn't recompile (webfarm)

Tags: asp.net, iis

i have few virtual PCs in a webfarm setup. each of the PCs are setup to run webserver which points to the same network share folder.

problem I'm facing is, whenever I do changes to `global.asax`, `web.config`, or in `app_code` folder, it doesn't recompile. restarting IIS, PC, or recycling application pool has no effect.

I had to delete the files in `"windows\microsoft.net\framework64\v4.0.30319\temporary asp.net files\root\"`, only then it will recompile with the new file changes. Shouldn't it recompile whenever there are changes to those files/folder?

what can I do to force it to recompile everytime there are changes to those?

Comment: Found a trick to force it to recompile, without stopping application pool. use c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe to set the compilation tempdirectory. the tempdirectory can be the same one everytime, and still it will recompile no matter. http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/creating-websites/provisioning-iis-7-sites-for-shared-hosting

Comment: Deleting the files in `windows\microsoft.net\framework64\...` works great for me.

Answer (score 0):

You should really not be relying on the fly compilation, I would recommend publishing your website as a precompile to the network share. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb398860(v=vs.100).aspx. Also app_code has some severe limitations, you should consider putting those classes in a separate assembly.

Comment: There are many reasons to use on demand compilation on the server. One of the top ones is the ability to make changes on the live server without having a full build environment.